# Uniform convergence of characteristic functions implies uniform convergence of distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

Let $F(x)$ and $(F_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be some distribution functions and let
$\varphi(t)$ and $(\varphi_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be their respective characteristic functions. I am trying to show that if:

$\sup_t |\varphi_n(t) -\varphi(t)| \rightarrow 0$, then

$\sup_x |F_n(x) -F(x)| \rightarrow 0$.

By Levy's theorem, I know that $F_n$ converges weakly to $F$. And I also know that, if $F$ is continuous, I have the result I want. So I believe I should use the uniform convergence of the characteristic functions to show that $F$ must be continuous.

I am trying to show that I must have:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\varphi(t)|dt < \infty$

which would imply that $F$ is continuous, but I am stuck at that. Anyone can shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: "I must have" is not necessarily what you should have. Because that'll imply F(.) is not only continuous but also absolutely continuous w.r.t. lebesgue measure i.e. has density f(.). But there are distributions which are continuous but has no density e.g. cantor function.

Comment: @Saty Good point. But now I don't even know where to start. Any clue?

Comment: I did not know until you asked it here and I searched google. Seems like there is a paper on it! Thanks for asking such a good question. have a look at it http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-088-01/S0002-9939-1983-0691296-X/S0002-9939-1983-0691296-X.pdf